# Is there a way with javascript to search my xml for attributes and get the whole parentelement back who has this attribute in it?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

I'm very new to XML and Javascript. 
I have have this in my html:

```
<select id="eigenschaften" name="eigenschaften" type="text" onchange="">
    <option value="">Eigenschaft wählen</option>
    <option value="gesellig">gesellig</option>
    <option value="ruhig">ruhig</option>
    <option value="unkompliziert">unkompliziert</option>
    <option value="temperamentvoll">temperamentvoll</option>
    <option value="neugierig">neugierig</option>
    <option value="verschmust">verschmust</option>
    <option value="intelligent">intelligent</option>
</select>
```

These values are attributes from my xml. I want to search my xml for these attributes and get not just the element which contains the attribute, but the whole parent element back.
Is this possible with javascript?

I started with basic ajax:

```
function loadXmlDocument(url) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {  // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            xmlDocument = xmlhttp.responseXML;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

But am kind of stuck now.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Example :
demo.xml data

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<user>
  <details>
    <name>abc</name>
    <class>xyz</class>
    <city>pqr</city>
  </details>
  <info>
    <id>123</id>
    <code>456</code>
  </info>
</user>

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "/path/demo.xml", false);
request.send();
var xml = request.responseXML;
var users = xml.getElementsByTagName("user");
for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    var names = user.getElementsByTagName("name");
    for(var j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
        alert(names[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using JQuery then                                                                     var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
  $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
  $title = $xml.find( "title" );

Comment: Thanx for your reply but what about my problem with attributes?

Comment: I accidently edited under your answer, but here it is

Comment: Yes, but I only find a way for getting attributes from my xml not for what I want to do